# Cannot connect to Android emulator (10.0.2.x) from Macbook (192.168.0.x)

Tags: networking, android

Using Android Studio, I noticed that the IP of the Android emulator was 10.0.2.16 while the host Macbook has 192.168.0.x and other devices (and VMs on the same Mac) all have 192.168.0.y.
I tried to do `sudo ip a add 192.168.0.70/16 dev wlan0` in the emulator (Termux) which did work as it showed in `ip a`. And I did the same on the Macbook terminal `sudo ip a add 10.0.2.70/16 dev en0` (these commands do need root, but worked), so both have a virtual IP address in the other subnet. But still the Mac cannot connect to the Android emulator.

I have one single Linksys router which has the 192.168.0.x subnet.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Please read https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#redirection Qemu has no virtual network interface on host side so direct access to the guest network is not really possible. If you need this use a VirtualBox based Android emulator like Genymotion.